# Xcode memory viewer: byte grouping control

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Xcode's [memory viewer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/viewing_memory.html) states that there should a "byte grouping" control at the bottom of the memory viewer. I just checked Xcode 7.3.1 and the latest beta 8 release... I don't see that control. Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is indeed missing from the debugger controls, although, still available via:

```
Xcode > Editor > Byte Grouping
```

It's not clear why the function controls disappeared from the debugger area itself...